# I am redirected to my site homepage when I login using mysite/wp-admin instead of getting to the wordpress admin page

Tags: wordpress

I am getting redirected to my website homepage when I login to the admin area in Wordpress or I get an error message saying 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page'

I just migrated my website from one host provider to another using the All in One WP migration plugin. I was able to access the admin area but once the backup, I am either being redirected to my homepage or getting the above error when I try to login. I have already tried to create a new user with admin privileges, modified the wp-config and htaccess files and even updating and changing the prefixes of the database. I have also tried disabling the plugin and theme files and none of them seem to work.

I just want to be able to login to the admin area of my WordPress site.

Comment: Use `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in wp-config.php to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases the steps I follow to resolve this case are:

> Set .htaccess with *only* the default WordPress redirect rules, which you can check [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp).
>
> Set the default TwentyNineteen theme as active. Since you do not have access to your admin dashboard you can perform this change by altering the "*template*" and "*stylesheet*" rows in your application database which both are located in the "*_options*" table.
> The other option is via SSH. From the WordPress root directory you can execute the following command, which will change the currently active theme to TwentyNineteen:

```
wp theme activate twentynineteen
```

**NOTE:** No matter which option you choose the TwentyNineteen theme should be installed. If you have other WordPress default theme installed rather than TwentyNineteen, you can switch to it.

> Deactivate all of the plugins. This can also be performed in two ways without access to the admin dashboard. The first option is to rename the *wp-content/plugins* folder to:

```
wp-content/plugins-backup
```

The other option is once again via the WP CLI tool with the next command:

```
wp plugin deactivate --all
```

**Another NOTE:** In order to use the WP CLI tool, please note that the same should be installed on the server. If you write the command and the terminal respond is:

```
-bash: wp: command not found
```

Or something similar ending with "*command not found*" this means that the tool in question is not installed. In this case you will be unable to use the WP CLI tool or you can ask your hosting provider to install this tool for you.

In my experience with this issue, after all of these changes are performed the access to the admin dashboard is restored. If the issue still persist even after the changes are applied, I would recommend you to contact your current host provider in order to understand if they have any custom Web Application Firewall (WAF) rules, default plugins/optimizations that could cause such issue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will try this first thing tomorrow morning and will let you know the result!

Comment: I have tried the methods you have mentioned. The template and stylesheet rows were not available in the wp_options table but I deleted all the other themes from the file manager and disabled all plugins and tried to log in to the admin area. Unfortunately I was still redirected to the homepage, however this time it was just a blank white page instead of displaying my website homepage. I was able to access my website homepage by enabling the theme and the plugins again. Do you know any other ways to make it work. I have been stuck on this since 2 days and it would be really helpful if you did!

Comment: The blank page is shown because there is no theme files. The "_template_" and "_stylesheet_" rows should be available otherwise the database could be not complete. If you are using phpMyAdmin tool for administering the database they are usually on the second page of 25 rows that are visible by default. Could you please double check this? Also please check if there is _error_log_ file in the root directory of WordPress and if such file exist in the wp-admin folder as well. If there are such files what are the latest lines in them?